# Is there a way I can avoid these nested loops?

Tags: performance, loops, optimization, fortran, nested-loops

I need to make function calls with the values for each variable (wndspeed, xh, yh, A, and B)
Does anyone have an idea on how I can do it without using these nested loops?

```
  do i=1,windsteps  
     wndspeed =windinc*float(i-1)+windstart           

     write(*,*)i,wndspeed

     do j=1,ixsteps
        xh=xinc*float(j-1)
        xh=xh/height

        do k=1,iysteps
           yh=10.*float(k-1)*1e3
           yh=yinc*float(k-1)      
           yh=yh/height

           do l=1,iasteps
              A=(ainc*float(l-1)+50)*1e3     


              do m=1,ibsteps
                 B=binc*float(m-1)+1



                 Pdelt=wndspeed*wndspeed*rho*exp(1.)/B

                 call trackslopes(elevang,wndspeed,coxmkcor,skewpeak,
 1                    numslops,slopary,tanumax,xh,yh,A,B,Pdelt,height,numchips,
 2                    bkgrdwnd,antgain)
                 skewpeak=0

                 call trackconvolve(height,tanumax,numslops,slopary,numchips,
 1                    stppchip,deadband,elevang,convary)


enddo
enddo 
enddo
enddo
```

Comment: You need to find a better O(n^x) algorithm. This seems to be O(n^5) for now maybe you can find the independent ones so can reduce to n^4 but need to see inside of trackslopes.

Comment: Have you looked into [Elemental](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/elemental) procedures?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm totally new to fortran so no, but I am reading it now.

Comment: What's your problem with nested loops ?  If you want to compute a value on every point in a 5-D space nested loops are the way to go.  If you don't write 'em the compiler will (which may not be a bad approach).  What is your objective in searching for ways to eliminate the loop nest ?

Comment: As Mark already wrote, the nested loops are the way to go. You could still try to use some special loop constructs (e.g. `do concurrent`... ) to get this calculated in parallel.

Comment: Just a detail, I see 5 do and 4 enddo

Comment: to speed things up replace all unnecesary multiplications with addition (in loop a=i*b is the same as a+=b but much slower) also int->float conversions inside loops can be avoided in your case. avoid divisions a/b is slower than c=1.0/b; ... a*c; when c is computed before loop of course. What the calls do ? (they can be speed up possibly too)

Comment: Your two subroutines are probably taking up all your CPU cycles.  The nested loops you have are already very clean and sparse.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the trackslopes/trackconvolve procedures can be reduced to something simple, then there is no way to (non-trivially) remove the nested loops.

The best way to see this is that each sub-loop depends on the values of at least one of its super-loops, so that unless the inner-most computation is such that the entire process can be simplified mathematically, it is already in its simplest form.

If you just don't like looking at that many levels of nesting, you can try to flatten the 5-D space by using an array of indices instead of 5 distinct indices, and then you have to write a fairly ugly 1-D loop which checks the bounds of each of the 5 indices and then advances the index array appropriately.